# How to understand "to" in bold?

Tags: prepositions

> The now-shuttered program allowed permanent residency for those who
>   committed 800,000 Canadian dollars (US$726,720) ***to a five-year
>   zero-interest loan***  to one of the country's provinces.

What does ***to*** mean in the bolded phrase?

Answer (score 1):

"to" is careless or even wrong. The writer means "as a loan to one of the provinces". Journalism - considering the haste with which such articles often have to be written such things happen, especially when the newspaper saves the money for proof-reading.

Answer (score 1):

"To" is the preposition for "committed".

[Commit to (definition 6b)](http://thefreedictionary.com/commit)

Comment: See also: **commit something to something:** *They'll have to commit more money to the project if it's to succeed.* --[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/commit) (commit, sense 4). Also note, the second *to* (*to one of the country's provinces*) belong to the word *loan*.